# Edit item of treeview that don't contains String

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

My goal is to simply  **edit the cell of a treeview** (to do so, I've read the doc of JavaFX).

**My problem** is that *my treeview doesn't contains `strings`*, but my own type of data, that is call : `Database`. I got the error : `Database$Variable cannot be cast to core.Database`.

Is it possible to implement a treeview with my own type ?

Here's the code that I use, with the help of James_D :

```
public class DatabaseStructureView extends TreeView<Object> {

    private Database db;

    @FXML
    private TreeView<Database> databaseStructureView;

    public DatabaseStructureView() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DatabaseStructureView.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

        databaseStructureView.setEditable(true);
        databaseStructureView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Database>,TreeCell<Database>>(){
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Database> call(TreeView<Database> param) {
                return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
            }

        });


    }

    private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<Database> {

        private TextField textField;

        public TextFieldTreeCellImpl() {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();

            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getString());
            setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Database item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        commitEdit(getDatabase(textField.getText()));
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private Database getDatabase(String text) {
            return new Database(text);
        }

        private String getString(){
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

    public void setDatabase(Database db) {

        this.db = db;

        TreeItem<Object> dbRoot = new TreeItem<>(db);
        dbRoot.setExpanded(true);

        for (Variable var : db.getVariables()) {
            dbRoot.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Object>(var));
        }
        setRoot(dbRoot);
    }

}
```

Here's my DataBase class :

```
public class Database {

public static class Variable {

    public static enum VariableType {

        NUMERIC, INTEGER, LOGIC, ORDONEE, NOMINAL, DATE
    }

    private String name;

    private VariableType type;

    private List<String> values;

    public Variable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void addValue(String value) {
        values.add(value);
    }

    public String getValue(int index) {
        return values.get(index);
    }

    public void addValue(int index, String value) {
        values.add(index, value);
    }

    public VariableType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public String calculerMinimum (){
        if(this.getType().equals(VariableType.INTEGER)){
            // Je convertit en entier les strings
            List<String> maColonneString = this.getValues();
            List<Integer> maColonneInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i < maColonneString.size(); i++){
                if(!maColonneString.get(i).equals("NULL")){
                    maColonneInt.set(i, Integer.parseInt(maColonneString.get(i)));
                }
            }

            return(Integer.toString(Collections.min(maColonneInt)));
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String calculerMaximum (){
        if(this.getType().equals(VariableType.INTEGER)){
            // Je convertit en entier les strings
            List<String> maColonneString = this.getValues();
            List<Integer> maColonneInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i < maColonneString.size(); i++){
                if(!maColonneString.get(i).equals("NULL")){
                    maColonneInt.set(i, Integer.parseInt(maColonneString.get(i)));
                }
            }

            return(Integer.toString(Collections.max(maColonneInt)));
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String calculerFrequence (String maValeurTemoin){
        List<String> maColonneString = this.getValues();
        int compteur = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < maColonneString.size(); i++){
            if(maColonneString.get(i).equals(maValeurTemoin)){
                compteur ++;
            }
        }
        return Integer.toString(compteur);
    }

    public String calculerMoyenne (){
        if(this.getType().equals(VariableType.INTEGER)){
            List<String> maColonneString = this.getValues();
            int somme = 0;
            int valeurNull=0;
            for(int i = 0; i < maColonneString.size(); i++){
                if(!maColonneString.get(i).equals("NULL")){
                    somme += Integer.parseInt(maColonneString.get(i));
                }
                else{
                    valeurNull ++;
                }
            }
            return (Integer.toString(somme/(maColonneString.size()-valeurNull)));
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }



    public String calculerVariance (){
        if(this.getType().equals(VariableType.INTEGER)){
            List<String> maColonneString = this.getValues();
            int sommeMul=0;
            int variance=0;
            int valeurNull=0;
            for(int i = 0; i < maColonneString.size(); i++){
                if(!maColonneString.get(i).equals("NULL")){
                    sommeMul += Integer.parseInt(maColonneString.get(i))*Integer.parseInt(maColonneString.get(i));
                }
                else{
                    valeurNull ++;
                }
            }
            variance = sommeMul/(maColonneString.size()-valeurNull)-Integer.parseInt(calculerMoyenne())*Integer.parseInt(calculerMoyenne());
            return Integer.toString(variance);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String calculerEcartType (){
        if(this.getType().equals(VariableType.INTEGER)){
            return (Double.toString( Math.sqrt(Integer.parseInt(calculerVariance()))));
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<String> calculerAnalyseUnivarieRestreinte (){
        if(this.getType().equals(VariableType.INTEGER)){
            List<String> analyseUniList = new ArrayList<String>();
            analyseUniList.add(calculerMinimum());
            analyseUniList.add(calculerMaximum());
            analyseUniList.add(calculerMoyenne());
            return analyseUniList;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<String> calculerAnalyseUnivarieComplete (){
        if(this.getType().equals(VariableType.INTEGER)){
            List<String> analyseUniList = new ArrayList<String>();
            analyseUniList.add(calculerMinimum());
            analyseUniList.add(calculerMaximum());
            analyseUniList.add(calculerMoyenne());
            analyseUniList.add(calculerVariance());
            analyseUniList.add(calculerEcartType());
            return analyseUniList;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean rechercherValeur (String maValeurTemoin){
        List<String> maColonneString = this.getValues();
        return(maColonneString.contains(maValeurTemoin));
    }

    public void setTypeVariable (VariableType monNouveauType){
        this.type = monNouveauType;
    }

    public void setNomVariable (String monNouveauNom){
        this.name = monNouveauNom;
    }

    public void modifierValeur (String ancienneValeur, String nouvelValeur){
        List<String> maColonneString = this.getValues();
        for(int i = 0; i < maColonneString.size(); i++){
            if(maColonneString.get(i).equals(ancienneValeur)){
                this.values.set(i, nouvelValeur);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}


private List<Variable> variables;

private String name;

public Database(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    variables = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addVariable(String name) {
    variables.add(new Variable(name));
}

public String print() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;

    while (i != variables.get(0).values.size()) {
        for (Variable variable : variables) {
            sb.append(variable.values.get(i)).append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        i++;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public Variable getVariable(Variable maVariable) {
    for (Variable variable : variables) {
        if (variable.getName().equals(maVariable.getName())) {
            return variable;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Variable> getVariables() {
    return new ArrayList<>(variables);
}

public Variable getVariable(int index) {
    return variables.get(index);
}

public boolean addVariable(Variable variableAdd) {
    return (this.variables.add(variableAdd));
}

public boolean removeVariable(Variable variableRemove) {
    return (this.variables.remove(variableRemove));
}
```

}

And here's the errors that I get :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: core.Database$Variable cannot be cast to core.Database
at components.databaseStructureView.DatabaseStructureView$TextFieldTreeCellImpl.updateItem(DatabaseStructureView.java:53)
at javafx.scene.control.TreeCell.updateItem(TreeCell.java:515)
at javafx.scene.control.TreeCell.indexChanged(TreeCell.java:473)
at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has a strange structure: you have two `TreeView` references, the instance of the `TreeView<Object>` subclass (`DatabaseStructureView`), which is set as the dynamic root of the FXML, and then the `TreeView<Database>` reference you declare: `databaseStructureView`.

From what you describe, I can only assume (since you didn't create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) you have assigned both of these references to the same object, by setting the `fx:id` attribute on the root, something as follows:

```
<fx:root type="TreeView" fx:id="databaseStructureView" ... >
```

So what happens here is that both `this` (in the context of `DatabaseStructureView`) and `databaseStructureView` refer to the same object.

This is a highly confusing setup, and you should not do this. (Specifically, don't set an `fx:id` on a `<fx:root ... >` when the root is also the controller.)

What's happening is approximately the following:

Somewhere you do something like

```
TreeView<Object> treeView = new DatabaseStructureView<>();
```

This causes the fxml loader to load. Because you do `setRoot(this)`, it effectively does

```
Object root = treeView ;
```

(the type is `Object` because FXML is effectively untyped). Then because you have `setController(this)` the `FXMLLoader`'s controller is also set to `treeView`. And then when it parses the FXML, it sees the `fx:id` and also sets `databaseStructureView` to `treeView`. So you actually have `treeView.databaseStructureView == treeView`. You can verify this by adding

```
System.out.println(this == databaseStructureView);
```

after the `FXMLLoader`'s `load()` method has successfully completed.

Because of type erasure, and because all the assignments from the `FXMLLoader` are made by reflection, the generic types are invisible, so the FXML root, which has a compile time type of `TreeView<Object>` and `databaseStructureView`, which has a compile time type of `TreeView<Database>`, both have runtime types of a raw `TreeView`. So these reflective assignments are all successful.

But what has happened is that by using reflection in the FXML loader, you now have made a non-typesafe assignment, so all bets on the generic types are off. Because `databaseStructureView` has a compile-time type of `TreeView<Database>`, the compiler thinks it is safe to assume that all tree items in that tree must be `TreeItem<Database>`. So your `updateItem(...)` method takes a `Database` as a parameter. However, since the current object is a `TreeView<Object>`, the compiler will allow you to add any `TreeView<Object>` to the tree structure. But since they refer to the same thing, when you do

```
dbRoot.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Object>(var));
```

you are adding a `TreeView<Object>` to the tree structure of `databaseStructureView`. When the tree view later retrieves the wrapped object (really a `DatabaseStructure.Variable`) and passes it to the `updateItem(...)` method, you get a class cast exception because it is the wrong type.

This is obviously quite confusing: the confusion though comes from having the unnecessary reference `databaseStructure` which is really identical to the current object. If you remove that reference entirely, and the `fx:id` attribute, then you can just replace any references to `databaseStructureView` with `this`. What will then happen is that the type errors you have will be detected at compile time, not at run time (it won't let you set a `Callback<TableView<Database>, TableCell<DataBase>>` as the cell factory, for example, as it now (correctly) expects a `Callback<TableView<Object>, TableCell<Object>>`).

The underlying problem that is preventing you from doing what you want is that all items in a `TreeView` have to be the same type. You are trying to mix types: some `TreeItem`s contain `Database` objects, others contain `Database.Variable` objects. You need to either design your object model so that everything has a common type, or write the cell implementation to be a `TreeCell<Object>` and somehow figure out the correct objects to create when you commit an edit.